# Can we scan barcodes when we are using the power apps on the web

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, power-platform, barcodes

We have 2 fields: one which is a free text and the other is a combo-box. we have 2 barcodes, so can we scan the 2 barcodes and add their values inside the text and the combo-box fields?

As I were watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWUvttbYpu4 back to May 2019, which mentioned that scanning bar codes only work when accessing the power apps from you mobile and not from the web inside a laptop.

So any advice?

Answer (score 1):

As per Microsoft official documentations:

1. [Barcode scanner control in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-new-barcode-scanner)
2. [Limitations of controls in canvas apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/control-limitations)

> When using desktop browsers, the barcode scanner isn't supported. Use the Power Apps for mobile app.
>
> The barcode scanner control is only supported on Android and iOS devices. All other platforms will show a warning that some features of the app won't work.

---

**Update**:

I can see there is one experimental feature available in power apps settings for web barcode scanner. I am not sure if this is supported yet or fully functional (experimental features are not recommended by Microsoft to use in production apps). But, you can enable it from settings & try using it:

[image]

Then you can insert the control from **Insert > Media**:

[image]

Comment: Hi @John, does this answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

The scanner automatically detects a barcode, a QR code, or a data-matrix code when in view. The control doesn't support scanning in a web browser. The barcode scanner control is only supported on Android and iOS devices. All other platforms will show a warning that some features of the app won't work.

This May Work,
Peter